# Parse Cloud Code: beforeDelete not called for Installation on reinstallation

Tags: parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I noticed that at some point(?) Parse update the behavior of Installations so that if a user deletes your app and reinstalls it, the old Installation associated with that device gets deleted.

However, when Parse does delete this old Installation automatically, it doesn't seem like `Parse.Cloud.beforeDelete(Parse.Installation, function(request, response) {})` is called.

Is there a way to trigger some code either when an installation is deleted by Parse or upon reinstallation of your app? (Unsurprisingly, it doesn't seem like there's any way to detect *when* your app in uninstalled.)